# Is it possible to send real time notification to my python app whenever my MySQL data base change (insert)?

Tags: python, mysql, notifications, real-time

I am working on WSN network and for that, I created a MySQL database where I save the state of the sensor and whenever the state of the sensor changes It inserts a new line in that database with the state and time. Then I created an interface using python and I want to have the state of my sensor to be shown in that interface and whenever it is changed in the MySQL database it changes in the interface (in real time). So I want to know is that possible to have a notification sent from the MySQL database to my python app whenever that value changes ??

Comment: In order to do some action on insert - use trigger.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to execute the trigger in python, and i didn't find a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

You may set up a trigger and execute script through UDF. Have a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-udf.

> A.5.11.
>
> Can triggers call an external application through a UDF?
>
> Yes. For example, a trigger could invoke the **sys_exec()** UDF.